# flyspell-mode disables Greek accents

Tags: emacs, flyspell

When `flyspell-mode` is enabled and I try to write in Greek, I get an error most of the times I try to type an accent above some character:

```
<268632064> is undefined
```

The normal sequence to type a character with an accent is to first type ', followed by the appropriate vowel. Instead, whenever `flyspell-mode` is on, ' and the previously typed character are interpreted as a call to `<268632064>`, whatever that may be, which triggers an error, and, thus, the following character appears as is without an accent.

So,

when `flyspell-mode` is off, `λ ' ε` -> `λέ`

when `flyspell-mode` in on, `λ ΄ ε` -> `λε` and an `<268632064> is undefined` error

Note: I'm using GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0, NS appkit-1504.83 Version 10.12.6 (Build 16G29)) on a mid-2015 macbook pro.